Static Files no longer serving on Google App Engine Flex (PHP 8.3 / Ubuntu 22 / Yii2)
I had an appengine PHP 7.4 Yii2 site but as that version depreciated I upgraded to 8.3.  It runs but it can't find any of the static files (CSS etc.) that used to just work.
I've tried lots of different configuration but according to this:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/serving-static-files?tab=php it should just work.
Here is my app.yaml
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
    operating_system: ubuntu22
    runtime_version: 8.3
    document_root: web

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

I just get 404 on any static file; they all seem to route into the index.php file

Please update your question to show the structure of your project folder. Do you have the static content in the project's "web" folder?

Can only support if you provide your structure of the app and some configuration related to assets
